# watir install report failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir

I've installed a instantrail2.0.  I want to install watir 1.65

First I installed watir-1.6.5.gem it said 302 fetching http://gems.r....

then I downlord a rubygems-update-1.3.7.gem and type

```
gem install --local rubygems-update-1.3.7.gem
```

successfully installed.
then I type in `update_rubygems`

next I type in `gem install watir-1.6.5.gem`
but it appears `ERROR:Failed to build gem native extension`

I searched and found an answer that 1.3.7 doesn't support win32.
then I type

```
gem install sqlite3-ruby -v 1.3.0  gem install watir-1.6.5.gem
ERROR:Failed to build gem native extension

gem install sqlite3-ruby -v 1.2.3  gem install watir-1.6.5.gem
ERROR:Failed to build gem native extension
```

How can I do next??

Comment: Why are you installing rubygems 1.3.7 and watir 1.6.5. Why don't you install a current version of rubygems and watir gems?

Comment: What platform are you installing onto? That might be a rather important bit of information

Answer (score 1):

use a more current version of Watir

Answer (score 1):

I second Zeljko, going with the latest versions of rubygems and watir totally makes sense.  If you must stick to older gems, try installing Ruby DevKit and then do the gem install to see if that helps.

Comment: I want to install ruby on windows platform (XP or 2003),but I can hardly visit the website http://rubyforge.org/...And thank you for your help~

Answer (score 1):

What version of Ruby are you using? You should be using Ruby 1.8.6 with that version of Watir. I am also wondering if part of your problem is that you are doing a local install, instead of installing from internet. Local installs of Watir are difficult because of all of its dependencies.